# Indesign conditional text styling using ExtendScript

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

Does anyone know if it's possible to style text a certain way using ExtendScript, only when a certain condition is met for the paragraph in question?

I've cobbled together an ExtendScript script that I use in InDesign to fix text styles when they aren't fixed properly by the Paragraph Style tool, and it works well so far - changing Courier and Arial Unicode text to Times New Roman and fixing the font size - but i would really like to include a function that changes Times New Roman Italic to Times New Roman Bold Italic - but ONLY when the paragraph it appears in has a first letter that is set in Univers. Is there a way I can include an 'if' statement that will only trigger this style change in those circumstances?

Here's my existing code:

```
  var mydoc = app.activeDocument;

var theFontSize = [
  'Courier New','16','Courier New','8.75',
  'Times New Roman','16','Times New Roman','8.75',
];

for (i = 0; i < (theFontSize.length/4); i++) {

  app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
  app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
  app.findTextPreferences.appliedFont = theFontSize[i*4];
  if (theFontSize[(i*4)+1] != ''){
    app.findTextPreferences.pointSize = theFontSize[(i*4)+1];
  };
  app.changeTextPreferences.appliedFont  = theFontSize[(i*4)+2];
  if (theFontSize[(i*4)+3] != ''){
    app.changeTextPreferences.pointSize  = theFontSize[(i*4)+3];
    };
    mydoc.changeText();
  };

var theFontReplacements = [
  'Courier New','Regular','Times New Roman','Regular',
  'Courier New','Italic','Times New Roman','Italic',
  'Courier New','Bold','Times New Roman','Bold',
  'Courier New','Bold Italic','Times New Roman','Bold Italic',
  'Courier New','75 Black','Univers','75 Black',
  'Arial Unicode MS','Regular','Times New Roman','Regular',
];

for (i = 0; i < (theFontReplacements.length/4); i++) {

  app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
  app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
  app.findTextPreferences.appliedFont = theFontReplacements[i*4];
  if (theFontReplacements[(i*4)+1] != ''){
    app.findTextPreferences.fontStyle = theFontReplacements[(i*4)+1];
  };
  app.changeTextPreferences.appliedFont  = theFontReplacements[(i*4)+2];
  if (theFontReplacements[(i*4)+3] != ''){
    app.changeTextPreferences.fontStyle  = theFontReplacements[(i*4)+3];
  };
  mydoc.changeText();

};

app.findTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
app.changeTextPreferences = NothingEnum.nothing;
```

Comment: Your code is a bit too obscure. Among other things, I don’t understand why you’re testing against `''`, as `''` doesn’t appear in your data. Also, `theFontSize` is used to store values that aren’t font sizes, such as `'Courier New'`.
A trimmed down version would be easier for us to understand.
I don’t think you can do what you’re asking using `changeText`. Have you considered going through the results of `findText` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you started. It will be slower than using `changeText`, but I don’t think you can do what you’re asking with `changeText`.

```
// Change applied font of text set in Times New Roman Italic in paragraphs whose first character is set in Univers to Times New Roman Bold Italic

app.findTextPreferences.appliedFont = 'Times New Roman';
app.findTextPreferences.fontStyle = 'Italic';

var foundItems = app.activeDocument.findText(); // Set foundItems to all results of search according to app.findTextPreferences
for (var i = 0; i < foundItems.length; i++) { // For each result found
    var item = foundItems[i];
    if (item.paragraphs[0].characters[0].appliedFont.name.indexOf('Univers') == 0) { // If item’s first enclosing paragraph’s first character’s font name starts with “Univers”
        item.appliedFont = 'Times New Roman\tBold Italic'; // Set item’s font to Times New Roman italic
    }
};
```

Comment: Hi @Philippe-André Thanks for taking the time to look at this for me. Apologies for the delay - in the time between me posting this and you finding it my wife and I had a baby, so my mind has been elsewhere for a few weeks! I tried adding your code into my script, and then just on its own, but each time i run it I get an error saying that foundItems.forEach is not a function. I did some research and thought maybe foundItems needed to be turned into an Array, but this didn't seem to fix things either. I still get an error telling me it isn't a function. Apologies - perhaps it is just babybrain!

Comment: @EdClarke My mistake, there is no forEach in ExtendScript. I replaced it with a for loop; can you try the new version?

Comment: Amazing! this works perfectly (although with one slight change - in the 'if' statement i changed `item.appliedFont = 'Times New Roman/tBold Italic'` to `item.fontStyle = 'Bold Italic'`) Thank you so much for your help. this is now the perfect script for my team and me. I can't tell you how much repetitive formatting hassle this will save us!